# The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MyActivity

Tags: android, methods, fragment

Since I've been using my code, I used fragments.

To do so, I have an activity calling a fragment using a fragment by tag :

```
FluxListFragment FLF = (FluxListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAG_LIST);
```

But since today, getFragmentManager seems to be unrecognized. It says :

```
"The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type FluxMainActivity"
```

Is the problem coming from the build target ? (I put Android 3.0)

Here is the code :

```
public Class FluxMainActivity extends Activity {

@override
public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    FluxListeFragment FLF = (FluxListeFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAG_LISTE);    
}

}
```

The method should be linked to FluxListeFragment and not FluxMainActivity ! I think the cast is incorrect.

Comment: what you extend in your FluxMainActivity ?

Comment: Please, add the code of your activity including the packages you are using.

Comment: Ok I'll add my code. Chirag, FluxMainActivity is an extension of Activity.

Comment: Please extend Fragment or ListFragment .

Comment: FluxListFragment is already an extension of ListFragment, my FluxMainActivity uses FluxListFragment as a ListFragment extension.

Comment: Is it also a 3.0 device/avd your testing on?

Comment: yep, it's 3.0, the code has been added, below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved.

The project target was in API 11, but it contained 2 libraries with one of them in target API 8.