# Can't display the gmap on android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am displaying the map like this:

```
    GoogleMap googleMap =  ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

But, I am getting following error

```
The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type 
 MapActivity
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to extends your Activity by FragmentActivity, You can not use MapActivity with new Google map api v2. Second, you need to create map api key proper(i.e. debug key and live key both are different).

Answer (score 0):

Check if your target api is 11 or greater, but also check if libraries you use maybe target api 8. Check this: [The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MyActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596946/the-method-getfragmentmanager-is-undefined-for-the-type-myactivity)

Comment: Its 15    `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />`  and I am using Google APIs 2.2, that targets api 8.

Comment: Change Google APIs 2.2 to Google APIs 3.0 or greater