# v4 getFragmentManager with Activity - Incompatible types

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have a simple activity which runs as expected.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
// import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager(); // ActionBarActivity
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); // Activity
    }
}
```

I then replaced

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
```

with

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

so I could support my older devices.. However, this reports an error:

```
Incompatible types.

    Required: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

    Found: android.app.FragmentManager
```

What am I doing wrong here?

The popular solution I found is to use getSupportFragmentManager() instead, but this only works for ActionBarActivites [edit - see answers] and FragmentActivities.

[cannot convert from android.app.FragmentManager to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690364/cannot-convert-from-android-app-fragmentmanager-to-android-support-v4-app-fragme?rq=1)

The other relevant solution points to using a FragmentActivity instead, but this appears to have the same legacy problems.

[The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MyActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596946/the-method-getfragmentmanager-is-undefined-for-the-type-myactivity)

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager(); // ActionBarActivity
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure the solution to this will be on SE already, but it isn't easy (for me) to find. The minimal example should help other people with understanding it, too.

- I'm fairly new to Android.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In your first case if you use `getSupportFragmentManager()` you need to extend `FragmentActivity` or extend `ActionBarActivity` (extends FragmentActivity) as `FragmentActivity` is the base class for support based fragments.

In your second case you need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Fragments were introduced in honeycomb. To support fragments below honeycomb you need to use fragments from the support library in which case you need to extend `FragmentActivity` and use `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: This isn't the original question as a solution has now been found, but why can I not use a standard activity? Surely the v4 support should allow the activity to function in the same way as the new APIs. Secondly, now I am having to use a FragmentActivity instead of an activity, are there likely to be any other knock-on effects with my code?

Comment: @David use FragmentActivity if using v4. Nothing to worry use all imports from support library. I answered both the cases if you read the post again. The incomaptible types is becasue you need to use imports from support library

Comment: Thanks for your help, you and Rod. I've also found this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477997/difference-between-activity-and-fragmentactivity - that may be useful for those interested.

Comment: @David read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html. See this   `↳  android.app.Activity
 ↳ android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity ↳ android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`.

Answer (score 4):

```
use getSupportFragmentManager() instead, but this only works for ActionBarActivites.
```

Wrong, it should work in your `FragmentActivity`, that FragmentActivity is in your support package, when you are supporting older device then all your import from `activity`,`fragment`, `fragment managers`, etc. must have `android.support.v4.` to specify that you are using the support package. without using so will result to `incompatible compile time error.`

```
What am I doing wrong here?
```

You are combining support package with non support package which result to `incompatible compile time error`, as I said above.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. It works for FragmentActivities, too.

Comment: @David just make sure when you use support you must use the support package As I stated above. :))

Answer (score 2):

for Kotlin guyz u dont have to change to not v4

use below to get the activity as long as its the parent

```
(activity as MainDrawerActivity)
```

or

```
((YourActivityName)getActivity());
```

Answer (score 0):

For use in Java Dialog:

```
 - import android.app.FragmentManager;
 - FragmentManager fragmentManager;
```

For Kotlin :

```
 - (activity as? YourActivity)?.fragmentManager
```

Comment: In 2020, this is no longer correct. Because FragmentActivity will not implement FragmentManager anymore, it will contain FragmentManager.